# Independence of variables bound to NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array, let's call it `A`. The behavior of the following code is not clear to me:

```
b = A[3,:];
A[3,:] = 0;
```

The third row must be saved in `b`, but surprisingly `b` becomes zero also!

Any Help?

Comment: you normally don't need and you shouldn't use a semicolon at the line end in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a copy, you must, in fact, make a `copy`!

```
b = A[3,:].copy()
```

(By the way, python is not C: no semicolons after statements needed.)

Answer (score 2):

Migrating from MATLAB/Octave I see :-)?

1) Remember Python uses 0-based arrays as opposed to MATLAB's 1-based arrays.  `A[3,:]` will actually give you the 4th row.

2) Unlike MATLAB, taking a slice from an array like this stores the memory location of the slice from the *slicee* into the *slicer*.  Hence, as Andrew J. says, you need to copy.

Based on your statement that you want "The third row must be saved in b", your code should be

```
b = A[2,:].copy()
```

Comment: :-) it's the eye of experience.  After programming MATLAB for well over 6 years, I'm doing a lot of Python development lately.  Some of it requires a very different mindset to write "pythonic" code, but at least vectorization is still (generally) easily done!  Have fun.